# gem_package fails with Illformed requirement [""] in test kitchen

Tags: chef-infra, test-kitchen

Getting error 'Illformed requirement [""]' during the gem installation in test kitchen on windows platform:

```
I, [2017-03-24T15:17:54.108999 #2848]  INFO -- enable-windows: ---- Begin output of C:\opscode\chef\embedded\bin\gem install C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\kitchen\cache/rubyzip-1.2.0.gem -q --no-rdoc --no-ri -v "" ----
I, [2017-03-24T15:17:54.108999 #2848]  INFO -- enable-windows: STDOUT: 
I, [2017-03-24T15:17:54.108999 #2848]  INFO -- enable-windows: STDERR: ERROR:  While executing gem ... (ArgumentError)
I, [2017-03-24T15:17:54.108999 #2848]  INFO -- enable-windows:     Illformed requirement [""]
I, [2017-03-24T15:17:54.108999 #2848]  INFO -- enable-windows: ---- End output of C:\opscode\chef\embedded\bin\gem install C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\kitchen\cache/rubyzip-1.2.0.gem -q --no-rdoc --no-ri -v "" ----
I, [2017-03-24T15:17:54.108999 #2848]  INFO -- enable-windows: Ran C:\opscode\chef\embedded\bin\gem install C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\kitchen\cache/rubyzip-1.2.0.gem -q --no-rdoc --no-ri -v "" returned 1
E, [2017-03-24T15:17:56.454839 #2848] ERROR -- enable-windows: Converge failed on instance .
E, [2017-03-24T15:17:56.454839 #2848] ERROR -- enable-windows: ------Exception-------
E, [2017-03-24T15:17:56.454839 #2848] ERROR -- enable-windows: Class: Kitchen::ActionFailed
E, [2017-03-24T15:17:56.454839 #2848] ERROR -- enable-windows: Message: WinRM exited (1) for command: [
$env:PATH = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH","Machine")
I, [2017-03-24T15:17:54.108999 #2848]  INFO -- enable-windows: Compiled Resource:
I, [2017-03-24T15:17:54.108999 #2848]  INFO -- enable-windows: ------------------
I, [2017-03-24T15:17:54.108999 #2848]  INFO -- enable-windows: # Declared in C:/Users/ADMINI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/common_libs/libraries/unzip.rb:15:in `block in install_zip_gems'
I, [2017-03-24T15:17:54.108999 #2848]  INFO -- enable-windows: 
I, [2017-03-24T15:17:54.108999 #2848]  INFO -- enable-windows: gem_package("rubyzip-1.2.0.gem") do
I, [2017-03-24T15:17:54.108999 #2848]  INFO -- enable-windows:   provider Chef::Provider::Package::Rubygems
I, [2017-03-24T15:17:54.108999 #2848]  INFO -- enable-windows:   action [:install]
I, [2017-03-24T15:17:54.108999 #2848]  INFO -- enable-windows:   retries 0
I, [2017-03-24T15:17:54.108999 #2848]  INFO -- enable-windows:   retry_delay 2
I, [2017-03-24T15:17:54.108999 #2848]  INFO -- enable-windows:   guard_interpreter :default
I, [2017-03-24T15:17:54.108999 #2848]  INFO -- enable-windows:   package_name "rubyzip-1.2.0.gem"
I, [2017-03-24T15:17:54.108999 #2848]  INFO -- enable-windows:   source "C:\\Users\\ADMINI~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\kitchen\\cache/rubyzip-1.2.0.gem"
I, [2017-03-24T15:17:54.108999 #2848]  INFO -- enable-windows:   cookbook_name "backup"
I, [2017-03-24T15:17:54.108999 #2848]  INFO -- enable-windows:   recipe_name "_install_windows"
I, [2017-03-24T15:17:54.108999 #2848]  INFO -- enable-windows:   gem_binary "C:\\opscode\\chef\\embedded\\bin\\gem"
I, [2017-03-24T15:17:54.108999 #2848]  INFO -- enable-windows: end
```

This error is coming in test kitchen only, I don't get this error, when I run chef-client on the VM directly.

In common_libs/libraries/unzip.rb,

```
node['common_libs']['ruby_gem']['installers'].each do |gem_file|
Chef::Log.info("Missing gem '#{gem_file}'...installing now.")

remote_file "#{Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]}/#{gem_file}" do
  source "#{node['common_libs']['ruby_gem']['url']}/#{gem_file}"
  action :create
end

gem_package gem_file do
  source "#{Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]}/#{gem_file}"
  action :install
end
end
```

In attribute file,

`default['common_libs']['ruby_gem']['installers'] = %w(rubyzip-1.2.0.gem zip-zip-0.3.gem)`

Comment: Does it fail if you change the resource name to `"rubyzip"`?

Comment: @coderanger - Which cookbook i should add as dependency to use 'rubyzip'. By the way, why this error is coming?

Comment: This is in one of your custom cookbooks called `common_libs`, so I have no idea where exactly you would have to change beyond just looking at the stack trace.

Comment: No, there is no such resource and i have given the common_libs/libraries/unzip.rb above.

Comment: It's not a perfect solution but try something like `gem_package gem_file[/^(.*?)-\d/,1] do`